# Switch the value of two fields in a variable depending on the language used

Tags: php

I have a script that is bilingual, English and Spanish. The values of the language variables are saved as arrays with their respective values in English and Spanish.

The sample language code is as follows:

```
if ($_SESSION['language'] == "english") {
    $lang['0'] ="Home";
    $lang['1'] ="Articles";
    $lang['2'] ="Categories";
} else {
    $lang['0'] ="Inicio";
    $lang['1'] ="Articulos de ";
    $lang['2'] ="Categorias";

for ($i=0; $i<count($lang); $i++)
    $lang[$i] = $lang[$i];
}
```

The problem I have is that with Spanish, sometimes the words are read in reverse order, specially if they are adjectives. For example, "Red Car" in English would translate to "Carro Rojo" to be correct (which literally translates back to English as "Car Red")

Using the code above as an example, I would like to have one header that reads "Wedding Articles", "Wedding" would be the value of a field, and "Articles" the value of the language variable, as such:

```
echo $category_name." ".$lang['1'];
```

If the user is reading the site in English, the name of the header would read correctly, as "Wedding Articles. But, if the user is reading the site in Spanish, it would read "Bodas Articulos de " instead of "Articulos de Bodas"

What I am doing right now is this:

```
if ($_SESSION['language'] == "english") {
echo $category_name." ".$lang['1'];
} else {
echo $lang['1']." ".$category_name;
}
```

Notice the reverse order.

What I am wondering is whether there is a function that reverses the order of two field values to meet another language's readability.

I am a level 0 php enthusiast and dont know all available functions. What I work on are examples I find in fine sites such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to achieve this, here's one below.

```
<?
$groupLabels = array(
   'sites' => array('Websites', 'Sitios de Web'),
   'articles' => array('Articles', 'Articulos de'),
   'categories' => array('Categories', 'Categorias')
);
$itemLabels = array(
   'car' => array('Car', 'Carro'),
   'book' => array('Book', 'Libro'),
   'food' => array('Food', 'Comida')
);

function getLabel($language, $group, $item) {
   global $groupLabels;
   global $itemLabels;
   if ($language == "english") {
      return $itemLabels[$item][0] . " " . $groupLabels[$group][0];
   } else if ($language == "spanish") {
      return $groupLabels[$group][1] . " " . $itemLabels[$item][1];
   } else {
      return "Language not found";
   }
};

echo getLabel('english', 'articles', 'car') . "<br />"; // yields "Car Articles"
echo getLabel('spanish', 'articles', 'car') . "<br />"; // yields "Articulos de Carros"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your meaning.
It's like Chinese and English,
     In English, using  'Firstname Lastname' 
     But in Chinese, We using 'Lastname Firstname'

We always do like this:
./locale/
  -English.php
  -Spanish.php

in the English.php

```
$lang = array(
    'red_car' => 'red car',
       ...
)
```

in the Spanish.php

```
$lang = array(
    'red_car' => 'Carro Rojo',
       ...
)
```

include the language file:

```
require_once(./locale/English.php)
```

or

```
require_once(./locale/Spanish.php)
```

using `$lang['red_car']` in the code